# Transfer data from MVC application server to JavaScript client continuously

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make an application that sends data from a MVC server side project and receives this data in a JavaScript call. Then the data is presented to user. The data consists of an array of integers with a limited length of ~ 1500 elements. This integers are computed on the server side and then used on the client side (in JavaScript) to draw a graph on a panel.

I have succeeded implementing this by exposing the array through an `HttpGet` method on the server side, and calling this method with Ajax from the client side. Once done this seems simple, the problem that I am facing right now is that I need to redraw the graph with fresh data which is continuously recomputed on the server. To solve this I have added `setInterval` on the function which calls the `HttpGet` method and redraws the canvas in JavaScript.

The problem I still have is that this approach does not seem so efficient since the JavaScript redraw is always waiting for the interval to complete, then it does the Ajax call and then the actual redraw is done. Is there anything I could do, or another approach I could choose to improve the performance of the draw, so the drawing could become more fluent?

Please excuse me for not providing any code, I can't find it suitable here.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you know how to use websockets(signalr)? You should give a try

Comment: @Cleiton I have read about websockets, but I am not sure if they could fit inside this architecture. If it seems possible to replace the `HttpGet` method call with websockets I guess they would improve the performance visibly. This is a reason why I have asked the question, to find alternatives like this one you just suggested to my approach. So I must thank you for it. Do you think that websockets will work on the client side (JavaScript) ?

Answer (score 1):

As Cleiton wrote, websockets are obvious choice. Also Socket.io, but I'm not sure if there is no official implementation in C# I guess.